# There are two elements in <template> when I creat a new Vue3 project, and my VScode warning

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

[image: vue3 error ploblem]

Guys i'm in the transition from vue2 to vue3.
As i know in vue2 you can't put **more than One element** in  `<template></template>`

But when i create a new Vue3 project, you can see the code in that picture.The author did that.
Is that allowed to put two element in `<template></template>` in vue3?

If it is, why my VScode warning the fourth line?

Comment: What is the actual error if you hover on it? Or open your `problems` tab (bottom left)?

Comment: Er..the terminal didn't say anything, just a red line under it ,usually I know it's syntax error message

Comment: Not in the terminal output. Hover on it or check the problems tab (`palette: >Problems: Focus on problems View`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The origin of the problem in most cases: Vetur

I see this problem a lot lately. The solution has always been the same: **uninstall Vetur and install Volar instead**, it is the new recommended extension for Vue 3.

As you can see Vue 3 no longer requires a single root node for components so you have some extension that does not detect it. Vetur has had trouble adapting to Vue 3. Maybe you have a version configured for Vue 2. In any case I recommend you Volar.

### If your problem is with eslint or another lintern

Look for this vue plugin specific rule in the .eslintrc config file or package.json:

```js
rules: { 
    ...,
    "vue/no-multiple-template-root": "off" 
}
```

Comment: What is the error tho?

Comment: @kissu Maybe a version of Vetur for Vue 2 and it doesn't detect sharding well (for multiroot elements)

Comment: Alright, I never saw this issue while still running both for all of my Vue2 + 3 projects. Depends maybe of the configuration.

Comment: Better to fix it than just ignore IMO.

Comment: @kissu I agree. It's probably a configuration problem. In any case I would not recommend dealing with discontinued extensions.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that Vetur may be called discontinued just yet. There are still some things to figure out/fix regarding Volar. I'm not totally in love with it just yet neither, will probably come soon but Vetur is still totally viable especially looking at all the projects still using Vue2.

Comment: @kissu You are right, I have chosen the wrong words. Discontinued is not the right word if there are still active developers on it. It has simply ceased to be the officially recommended one.